# The best approach to validate fields

Tags: java, spring

I wonder if there is a better approach to validate the object fields. For specific types of objects some fields cannot be empty:

```
public class CredentialsValidator {

  public boolean validateCredentialsRequest(ValidationCredentialsRequest credentialsRequest) {
    switch (credentialsRequest.getCredentialType()) {
      case TYPEA:
        return validatetypeACredentials(credentialsRequest);
      case TYPEB:
        return validateTypeBCredentials(credentialsRequest);
      case TYPEC:
        return validateTypeCCredentials(credentialsRequest);
    }
    return true;
  }

  private boolean validateTypeCCredentials(ValidationCredentialsRequest credentials) {
    if (credentials.getIsNewCredential()) {
      return nonNull(credentials.getUsername())
          && !credentials.getUsername().isEmpty()
          && nonNull(credentials.getPassword())
          && !credentials.getPassword().isEmpty();
    }
    return nonNull(credentials.getCredentialsId());
  }

  private boolean validateTypeBCredentials(ValidationCredentialsRequest credentials) {
    if (credentials.getIsNewCredential()) {
      return nonNull(credentials.getHostname())
          && !credentials.getHostname().isEmpty()
          && nonNull(credentials.getPort())
          && !credentials.getPort().isEmpty()
          && nonNull(credentials.getUsername())
          && !credentials.getUsername().isEmpty()
          && nonNull(credentials.getPassword())
          && !credentials.getPassword().isEmpty();
    }
    return nonNull(credentials.getCredentialsId())
        && nonNull(credentials.getHostname())
        && !credentials.getHostname().isEmpty()
        && nonNull(credentials.getPort())
        && !credentials.getPort().isEmpty();
  }

  private boolean validatetypeACredentials(ValidationCredentialsRequest credentials) {
    if (credentials.getIsNewCredential()) {
      return (nonNull(credentials.getDomain())
              && !credentials.getDomain().isEmpty()
              && nonNull(credentials.getUsername())
              && !credentials.getUsername().isEmpty()
              && nonNull(credentials.getPassword())
              && !credentials.getPassword().isEmpty())
          || (nonNull(credentials.getSharePoint().getUsername())
              && !credentials.getSharePoint().getUsername().isEmpty()
              && nonNull(credentials.getSharePoint().getPassword())
              && !credentials.getSharePoint().getPassword().isEmpty());
    }
    return nonNull(credentials.getCredentialsId())
        && nonNull(credentials.getDomain())
        && !credentials.getDomain().isEmpty();
  }
```

My main class that invokes Validator:

```
public Mono<ValidationCredentialsResponse> validateCredentials(
      Mono<ValidationCredentialsRequest> validationCredentials) {
    return validationCredentials
        .filter(credentialsValidator::validateCredentialsRequest)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new InvalidCredentialsException(MESSAGE)))
        .flatMap(
            validCredentials ->
                securityService
```

...
...

I use Spring Boot and Webflux for reactive programming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From an object-oriented point of view there is a better way you can handle this scenario.

## Feature Envy

Currently the code snipped has a Code Smell that is called [Feature Envy](http://wiki.c2.com/?FeatureEnvySmell):

> The whole point of objects is that they are a technique to package data with the processes used on that data. A classic [code] smell is a method that seems more interested in a class other than the one it is in. The most common focus of the envy is the data.
>
> — Martin Fowler, Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code, Chap. 3, p. 80

The class `CredentialsValidator` only interacts with data from `ValidationCredentialsRequest` by accessing it via all the getters:

> ```java
> nonNull(credentials.getUsername())
> && !credentials.getHostname().isEmpty()
> /* ... */
> ```

Instead, this logic could be in `ValidationCredentialsRequest`, and `CredentialsValidator` only interacts with the validation methods instead of the getters:

> ```java
> public boolean validateCredentialsRequest(ValidationCredentialsRequest credentialsRequest) {
>    switch (credentialsRequest.getCredentialType()) {
>        case TYPEA:
>            return credentialsRequest.isTypeAValid();
>        case TYPEB:
>            return credentialsRequest.isTypeBValid();
>        case TYPEC:
>            return credentialsRequest.isTypeCValid();
>    }
>    return true;
> }
> ```

> ```java
> class ValidationCredentialsRequest {
>    /* ... */
>
>    public boolean isTypeAValid() {/* ... */ }
>
>    public boolean isTypeBValid() {/* ... */ }
>
>    public boolean isTypeCValid() {
>        if (newCredential) {
>            return nonNull(username)
>                && !username().isEmpty()
>                && nonNull(password)
>                && !password.isEmpty();
>        }
>        return nonNull(credentialsId);
>    }
>
> }
> ```

## Polymorphism

[Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) is a concept where one thing can be something else at the same time: for example, a `Shape` can be a `Rectangle` at the same time.

With `Polymorphism` we can achieve that we no longer need the switch case. This would have the advantage that we don't have to change the `CredentialsValidator` class when adding new validation logic:

```java
class CredentialsValidator {
    
    public boolean validateCredentialsRequest(ValidationCredentialsRequest credentialsRequest) {
        return credentialsRequest.isValid();
    }
    
}
```

From here all different "shapes" of `ValidationCredentialsRequest` need to share the same interface - all need the `isValid` method:

```java
abstract class ValidationCredentialsRequest {
    /* ... */
    abstract boolen isValid();
}

class TypeARequest extends ValidationCredentialsRequest {
    /* ... */
    public boolean isValid() { /* ... */ }
}

class TypeBRequest extends ValidationCredentialsRequest {
    /* ... */
    public boolean isValid() { /* ... */ }
}

class TypeCRequest extends ValidationCredentialsRequest {
    /* ... */
    public boolean isValid() {
        if (newCredential) {
            return nonNull(username)
                && !username().isEmpty()
                && nonNull(password)
                && !password.isEmpty();
        }
        return nonNull(credentialsId);
    }
}
```

Now when a new kind of `ValidationCredentialsRequest` is needed, we just have to create a new "form" of it, and it works without changing the `CredentialsValidator`.

## Edit

### Use in Main

In the code for the main you provided nothing needs to be changed.

But if you would like to add the *Polymorphism* to your code, you need to change it where you create the `ValidationCredentialsRequest` objects. There you would create the different "shapes" of `ValidationCredentialsRequest` instead of `ValidationCredentialsRequest` itself.

Comment: And how to use it in my main class? I use the code above in that way:  return validationCredentials
        .filter(credentialsValidator::validateCredentialsRequest)

Comment: @Matley, could you add your main to your question above? I will give you an answer for it

Comment: I added main class above

Comment: But I dont understand something - ValidationCredentialsRequest  is my object with fields like username, password and I want to validate these fields if are null or not... Why do you suggest abstract class ValidationCredentialsRequest or class TypeARequest extends ValidationCredentialsRequest? I don't understand this part

Comment: ValidationCredentialsRequest has a field type like TypeA, TypeB, TypeC (enum)

Comment: So I think in my case it's difficult to use polymorphism - do you agree?

Comment: @Matley, no, it's not difficult. Because actually you try to create different types of `ValidationCredentialsRequest` through the enums in the class (so you imitate a kind of polymorphism). The disadvantage is that you always have to ask for the correct enum type, whereas with the correct polymorphism this is not necessary. If you add your `ValidationCredentialsRequest` I could give you a better description of it :)